# Insert column to make the primary key in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, insert, primary-key

I have a huge table (more than a million records) right now that currently contains the following 2 columns: `CustomerName` and `AmountBilled`

I want to add another column, which we can call it `PurchaseID`, so that `CustomerName` `+ PurchaseID` becomes a unique combination and hence I can create a primary key.

Say for example, my original data looks like this:

```
CustomerName AmountBilled
-------------------------    
Bill          $2
Bill          $3.5
Joe           $5
```

I want my new table to look like this:

```
Bill    1    $2
Bill    2    $3.5
Joe     1    $5
```

With the second column calculated in `SQL`.

What is the correct `SQL` statement for this?

Comment: This is whole bad idea, PK shouldn't be on strings, is bad for performance. Apart from that what happens if someone updates the name to some other that is already there with the same index? You should normalize this by having a `Customers` and a FK from your original table to `Customers` to find out the `CustomerName`.

Comment: Thanks @LuisLL, this is just an example I am making here for illustration purposes, the actual table looks much better than this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
alter table TableName
    add PurchaseID int NULL
GO
;with cte as (
  select *, rn = row_number() over (partition by CustomerName order by @@spid)
  from TableName
)
update cte set PurchaseID = rn
GO
alter table TableName
    alter column PurchaseID int not NULL
GO
```